# Dazzle DVC 100 with ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I've been trying to use my Dazzle DVC 100 with Ubuntu 21.04 but I can't seem to get it to works. It does work since I've used it with Windows 10 before, but it doesn't show up as a device in `/dev/video*`, and `v4l2` doesn't recognize it. The confusing thing is, `lsusb` lists it as

```
us 001 Device 007: ID 1b80:e60a Afatech Dazzle Video Capture USB Audio Device
```

Can anyone help me use this?

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2395314

Comment: This guide gets me nowhere; the guide itself is incomplete as the recipient never even got it working.

Comment: Unless there are Linux drivers for that device, it won’t work.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get mine working on Linux mint using OBS studio.

I made a new scene, then under sources I added a Video Capture device (V4L2) and set the device to Pinnacle Dazzel DVC 90/100/101/
This allowed me to see the video.
Next I added an Audio capture Device(ALSA) and selected DVC100 USB Audio to get the sound. Then you will see the audio level bars. You can then click the cog and pick advanced options to enable monitoring of the sound output if desired.

You can then record the output.

This answer may be 11 months late, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Did you do anything beforehand? I don't get this on ubuntu, only my webcam.